# How does java show exceptions without try-catch

Tags: java, exception

Java can show exceptions in the terminal although the error prone codes between try-catch block is not enclosed. How does Java do that?

Answer (score 3):

There is a global exception handling in JVM layer.

EDIT.

You can implement global exception handling using [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

Comment: is it possible to capture those exception messages from our java application?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)

Comment: See my edit. Thanks to @Martin Wilson that referenced this doc before me.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the Java API documentation, when a thread is going to
>   terminate due to an uncaught exception, the Java Virtual Machine *will
>   query* the thread for its **UncaughtExceptionHandler**

As our program has main Thread JVM ask main about Exception Handler by `Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler()`.

Than invokes handler by passing Thread and Exception as an argument to handle Exception